# Removing a value from a list and its sub-lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, sublist

I want to remove a specified value from a list and its sub-lists.  Here is my code:

```
example = [['x', 'y'], ['x', 'y'], ['x']]
value = 'x'
if value in example:
    example.remove(value)
    print(example)
```

In this case, value `'x'` appears in each of the sub-lists in the list `example`.  So this is the value I want to return:

```
[['y'], ['y'], []]
```

However, with my current method the output I get is:

```
[['x', 'y'], ['x', 'y'], ['x']]
```

Does anyone have a solution for my problem that outputs the list without the specified value?

Comment: You want to find the values which occur in all the inner lists?

Comment: Why do you want to use the `len()` function for this?

Comment: Have you tried to solve that on your own?

Comment: I don't specifically want to use len() but wondered if that may come into it...and yes I want to find the values which occur in each of the inner lists.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient of ways, but you can take the `union` to get all unique keys, then the `intersection` that again the original lists, eg:

```
inall = set().union(*your_list).intersection(*your_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
>>> l = [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['x', 'z', 'y'], ['x', 'z']]
>>> [item for item in l[0] if all(item in sublist for sublist in l[1:])]
['x', 'z']
```

If an item is in all sublists, it must be in the first sublist (`l[0]`). So we build our new list using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
[item for item in l[0]]
```

but we only want to use an item if that item is in all the other sublists as well (starting from `l[1:]`), which means we need to check

```
if all(item in sublist for sublist in l[1:])
```

Combine the two and you have your solution.

Comment: What if lists look like: `l = [['x', 'y', 'z', 'z'], ['x', 'z', 'y'], ['x', 'z']]`?

Comment: Good point, we could always use `set(l[0])` if that was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [['x', 'y'], ['x', 'y'], ['x']]

print(set.intersection(*map(set,l)))
set(['x'])
```